# There is web based bicycle routing planner that considers accidents but I cannot find it anymore, can someone help me?

Tags: google-maps, web-mapping, routing

I remember it uses Google as underlying map and has also a function to rank preferences of the path using forms in which the user can rate routes characteristics, I also remember that is for Los Angeles (but I am not sure about this). I came across this web map a couple of months ago but I did not save it as favourite. Now I have been searching continually for two days in many ways but I can't find it anymore.

Does someone know what I am talking about and please provide me the page URL?

Comment: I don't know about a webapp, but this research paper suggests bicycle routing while avoiding accident hot spots:
"Alex D. Singleton and Daniel J. Lewis, “Including Accident Information in Automatic Bicycle Route Planning for Urban Areas,” Urban Studies Research, vol. 2011, Article ID 362817, 10 pages, 2011. doi:10.1155/2011/362817"

http://www.hindawi.com/journals/usr/2011/362817/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it, it is worth having a look because I think there are not many safe route planners based on past accidents events http://opt.berkeley.edu

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick Google search, I believe what you're looking for is http://www.ridethecity.com

It defaults to New York, but you can select from a number of major cities in the United States, Canada, France, Spain, Australia, and a couple of others.  Very interesting application! And apparently (according to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/763/how-to-convert-line-simple-features-to-topological-network/772#772)) it's driven by PgRouting.

Comment: Actually it looks like it defaults to what it determines to be your location based on IP address.

Comment: @blah238 Strange, doesn't do that for me. The city I'm in is on the list, but it goes to New York. Maybe it's a cookies/privacy/track my location/browswer thing.

Comment: More likely a proxy/VPN thing than a browser thing (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotargeting).

Comment: @blah238 Not using a proxy or VPN - just regular open commercial cable provider. Google Maps loads to my city, MSN.com's local section is... well, close. Many pages can get my zip or city, just not that one. *shrug*

Comment: Thanks again, I knew the existence of that service (ride the city) but it is not what I am looking for.