# Alternatives to Network Analyst

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, routing, network-analysis

If I am looking to build a network based on road features and attributes, is Network Analyst my *best* bet?

Is it my **only** bet?

The world of FOSS (Free and Open Source) is new and exciting to me, but I find it difficult to navigate as a newbie.

My intended uses would include tracing the network, finding intersecting features at given locations along the network, and creating network decision rules for route creation.

---

Answers so far have been great, but could anyone share their personal experiences and preferences as far as routing interfaces are concerned?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are mostly interested in traversal/routing, go with [pgRouting](http://www.pgrouting.org/index.html).

If you don't find what you need to do there, [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/index.html) has a freakishly large number of algorithms for graphs and now [loads shapefiles out-of-the-box](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/readwrite.nx_shp.html) using OGR.

[nx_spatial](https://bitbucket.org/gallipoli/nx_spatial/wiki/Home) extends networkx in some minor ways mostly related to utility networks.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to browse this post:

- [Alternatives to pgRouting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210/alternatives-to-pgrouting)

and look through the previous posts using the [Network](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) and [Routing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/routing) tags

Answer (score 6):

spatiaite has routing capabiliies with a GUI. I have never tried it.
http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/spatialite-network-2.3.1.html

Answer (score 2):

GRASS GIS also has network analysis toolkit, take a look at the [`v.net.*` modules](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_network_analysis) and a detailed tutorial [here](http://www.ing.unitn.it/~grass/docs/tutorial_64_en/htdocs/esercitazione/network_analysis/)

Answer (score 1):

In Alpha release but looks promising:

**GeoDaNet** (Alpha) - *Spatial point pattern analysis on networks* (based on [PySAL](https://geodacenter.asu.edu/projects/pysal) Ptyhon library, concieved in GeoDa centre).

([Slides](https://geodacenter.asu.edu/drupal_files/GeoDaNet_Functionality.pdf), [manual](https://geodacenter.asu.edu/drupal_files/Geodanet_Manual_03_2012.pdf), [download](https://geodacenter.asu.edu/downloads/software/gnet).)

Answer (score 0):

Not open-source, but I have been using [RouteSmart](http://www.routesmart.com/industry-solutions/public-works-vehicle-routing-software-systems-vehicles-management-solutions/solutions/arc-gis-public-works-vehicle-routing-software-systems-solutions/) for some time, and recommend it highly. It's specifically designed to solve "high density" routing problems, i.e., those involving a very large number of points that must be serviced regularly. It is not an open-source product but imho worth investing to.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: developer plug for my own free product) [sDNA](http://www.cf.ac.uk/sdna)

It's not intended to replace network analyst, but to compute higher level statistics on networks (closeness, betweenness, severance, centrality etc).  The analyses are quite customizable.