# Are there any open source network analysis tools?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, network-analysis

A researcher in my field* recently created an "[Urban Network Analysis Toolbox](http://cityform.mit.edu/projects/urban-network-analysis.html)", an ArcGIS extension built upon Network Analyst. It calculates a number of measures on urban networks, such as betweenness and reach.

He was criticized for relying on ArcGIS, a commercial tool not available to many researchers, especially outside the US. But ArcGIS was a convenient platform, since it contains the Network Analyst extension, simplifying the work required for the analysis.

**Are there open source network analysis tools that do the work of the Network Analyst extension?** Are there other methods for creating the *network datasets* required as input for the toolbox? My understanding of the toolbox is that it uses the network dataset to calculate a distance matrix for a given set of points on the network. The toolbox does not use any of the higher level problem solving tools in Network Analyst.

**Quantitative Urban Morphology, perhaps? No one seems settled on a name for the broader field. The particular brand of research I do is with Space Syntax.*

Comment: [Network Analyst - Is it the only choice?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/network-analyst-is-it-the-only-choice) and [Alternatives to pgRouting](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210/alternatives-to-pgrouting) pretty much answer your question.

Comment: Oh, you're right. My cursory glance for questions didn't turn those up. Let's vote to close before more answers show up.

Comment: Once this is closed, it would be helpful to combine the other two under a useful title. [Alternatives to pgRouting](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210/alternatives-to-pgrouting) has better answers, but its title is less informative.

Answer (score 5):

There's [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html), a python graph/network analysis package. The list of network algorithms it supports is [here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not opensource (but freeware), the [CrimeStat](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/CrimeStat/index.html) program can calculate network distances. It takes as an input either a shapefile or a more arbitrary spreadsheet of to/from nodes.

Although not open source, the dll libraries are freely available to use (and so I would think would be available for use in other tools).