# Is there an open source tool for both road network analysis and geocoding?

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-gis, geocoding, analysis, network

Is there any one open source software package that can perform both road network analysis and geocoding?

Comment: For network analysis have a look at: [Network Analyst - Is it the only choice?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/network-analyst-is-it-the-only-choice) & [Alternatives to pgRouting](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210/alternatives-to-pgrouting)

Comment: For geocoding check: [Is there an open source Geocoding tool which can be used commercially?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18871/is-there-an-open-source-geocoding-tool-which-can-be-used-commercially)

Comment: I edited your question so that it only contains new aspects. The rest has been discussed separately already.

Answer (score 2):

There is or rather, there was. [PostLBS](http://en.giswiki.net/wiki/PostLBS) is a project which aims to provide core tools for Location Based Services (LBS) as Open Source Software (OSS) that can provide Routing (pgRouting) and Geocoding (geocoder.ja. Currently for Japan only) functionalities which are similar to those found on commercial software. Unfortunately, it seems to be gone now.