# Open Source Engine for Geocoding

Tags: geocoding, open-source-gis

I would create a service to geocode from existing shapefiles.  I know that ArcEngine does not allow the [creation of Windows Services](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisengine/common-questions).  Is there an open source option someone could recommend?

Comment: There are many relevant questions about this topic on our site.  Have you performed a search?

Comment: May be similar to this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20719/is-there-an-open-source-tool-for-both-road-network-analysis-and-geocoding OR http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18871/is-there-an-open-source-geocoding-tool-which-can-be-used-commercially

Answer (score 2):

The OpenStreetMap has an open source engine called Nominatim.

- Webiste: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/
- Documentation: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

You can make a query using this URL:

```
 http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?<params>
 http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/<query>?<params>
```