# Is it possible to route shapefiles using python and without ArcGIS, QGIS, or Pgrouting?

Tags: python, shapefile, routing

The question is pretty much in the title.

Is there a way to route through a road line shapefile using python and some library without having to resort to converting the data into PostGIS/pgrouting or going through desktop software API such as ArcGIS and QGIS?

Comment: Have you already looked at the [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/index.html) / [nx_spatial](https://bitbucket.org/gallipoli/nx_spatial/wiki/Home) combo as described in [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/alternatives-to-network-analyst/6812#6812)?  I haven't used it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The link given by MappaGnosis is the first attempt to implement Graph theory algorithms in Python (by Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python).

Since, many modules were developed:

- [Graph theory](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGraphApi)
- [network](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=network&submit=search)
- [routing network](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=routing%20network&submit=search)

One of the most comprehensive is [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/index.html), mentioned before in GS

- it can read or write shapefiles natively (thanks to bwreilly in [nx_spatial](https://bitbucket.org/gallipoli/nx_spatial/wiki/Home))
- all the graph algorithms are implemented ([Graph traversal](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.traversal.html), [Shortests Paths](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html) with the A* algorithm and many more)

```py
import networkx  as nx  
graph = nx.read_shp('lines.shp')  
print graph.nodes()  
[(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 2.0),...]  
print graph.edges()
[((1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 1.0)),...]
```

Result with matplotlib
[image]

Result with graphviz:
[image]

A* Algorithm

```py
def dist(a, b):
   (x1, y1) = a
   (x2, y2) = b
    return ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5

print(nx.astar_path(graph,(3.0,2.0),(1.0, 1.0),dist))
[(3.0, 2.0), (2.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0)]
```

and you can export the results:

to shapefiles:

```py
nx.write_shp(graph, ‘/shapefiles’)
```

to ogr geometries:

```
from osgeo import ogr
line = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
from points in (nx.astar_path(graph,(3.0,2.0),(1.0, 1.0),dist)):
    line.AddPoint(points[0],points[1])

print line.ExportToWkt()
LINESTRING (3 2 0,2 1 0,1 1 0)
```

or to [shapely](http://toblerity.github.io/shapely/manual.html) geometries:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
line = LineString(nx.astar_path(graph,(3.0,2.0),(1.0, 1.0),dist))
print line.wkt
LINESTRING (3.00 2.00, 2.00 1.00, 1.00 1.00)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. Thanks a lot for clarifying it so neatly. Now that I look at your example, I have an additional question, is it possible to do routing on any point on the line segment? or is it always from the nodes?

Answer (score 2):

'Yes' is the short answer.  However, you will need to implement the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).  [This link](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs.html) may be helpful for your implementation.  To read the shapefile you will probably want to use the [GDAL/OGR python libraries](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries) (and if you are on Windows I strongly recommend the 'gisinternals' link).

Answer (score 2):

Yes! A short answer, but I implement this little functionality in python-s2g (https://github.com/caesar0301/python-s2g).

```
import s2g
import networkx as nx

sg = s2g.ShapeGraph(shapefile='path/to/roads.shp', resolution=1.0)

assert isinstance(sg.graph, nx.Graph)
```

Use `resolution` parameter to adjust the spatial sampling, default 1 km in great circle distance.