# Postgis walk through multilinestring

Tags: postgis

Maybe question title not correct, i have no idea how to formulate my question.

Database is `postgres 9.2`, POSTGIS="2.0.2 r10789" GEOS="3.3.6-CAPI-1.7.6" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.7.8"

I have `roads` map from `OpenStreetMap` database. Geometry type is `MultiLineString`. For example, road from city `A` to city `B` consists of 27 entries in database (200 km total distance). One entry can be 500 meters another can be 70 kilometers. I want to analyse this road in fallowing scenario:

1. From city `A` take `40 km` in direction to city `B`.
2. Then analyse that path and in case if i need, go, for example, `5 km` back or forward.
3. Take another `40 km`, analyse until i reach city `B`.

How i can go `N km` from point `A`  to direction `B` via that road?
It is possible with SQL / postgis?

What i need is, plan where to place `green fuel station`. Electrical vehicle can drive average 50 km with full battery. So i need to analyze every `N km` if there is possible to build fuel station.
I already have data about rivers, electricity grid and another restrictions.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the solution will be related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44142/network-service-areas-in-qgis