# Grass gis or Qgis trade area?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I know it's possible to make a trade area (service area) in ArcGIS. But Is it possible to make a trade area with a network data set in Grass GIS or QGIs?

Comment: some notes/tutorials here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44142/how-to-calculate-network-service-areas-in-qgis and here https://jcastellssala.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/basic-network-analysis-with-grass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRASS GIS provides the `v.net.iso` module which is equivalent to the trade area in ArcGIS. See the documentation and examples based on distance and travel time: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.net.iso.html