# What do you call two isochrone maps that shows the intersection between two points as a "meeting" line?

Tags: terminology

I've learned today what isochrone maps are but now I sort of want to combine two isochrone so that a line forms right where the maps meet in the middle time wise.

As in, if each point travels the same amount of time then where will they meet? Under the assumption that each travels the furthest distance. That could be clockwise and counter clockwise.

On top of that it would be nice if of each "point" traveling could start at a different time and/or speed.

Comment: Are you describing [service area allocation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm) or [iso-area analyses](https://root676.github.io/)? Your last sentence makes it sound like you are looking for methods but you've tagged the question as terminology only.

Comment: @hgb I first wanted to know what I needed and if it has a name hence the terminology tag. It seems  service area allocation is what I wanted. Based on that image I see an border in between the points.  So with methods you mean which tools? I guess I would want to know that too but it seems QGIS + QNEAT3 can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our comments above, I think you are describing [service area allocation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm) or [iso-area analyses](https://root676.github.io/) problems.

These can be solved in a number of ways. The first link above points at solutions using ArcGIS network analyst. The second link refers to the QNEAT3 plugin for QGIS. But there is also a discussion of solutions to network service area problems using QGIS [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44142/how-to-calculate-network-service-areas-in-qgis).